# DialogFragment not showing, it opens and closes very quickly

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I'm pretty new at Android and was given a bunch of a client's source code at work to fix. The DialogFragment I'm trying to create won't stay open. When I step through it, it opens and then closes again right away when newFragement.show() is called.

My onCreateDialog keeps telling me that my current targetSdk is 8, but I've changed it back and forth to 11 multiple times, even restarted Android Studio, but still tells me it's wrong.

So far all the other posts I've found related to this haven't answered my question. I haven't been able to get FragmentActivity to work. Here's my code:

ShowUpgradeDialogFragment class:

```
public class ShowUpgradeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_builder_message)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_builder_positive, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // upgrade
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_builder_negative, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // User cancelled the dialog
                }
            });//*/
    System.out.println ("hello");
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    return dialog;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.ila.tax_shield"
      android:versionCode="18" android:versionName="3.2.4">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18"/>
<fragment android:name=".ShowUpgradeDialogFragment"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:windowIsFloating="true"
              android:background="@android:color/transparent"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</fragment>

// remaining manifest

</manifest>
```

my onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DialogFragment newFragment = new ShowUpgradeDialogFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");

    // code

    finish() // wrong and was removed, which solved my bug
   }
```

display_update_message.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment class="com.ila.tax_shield.fragments.ShowUpgradeDialogFragment"
          android:id="@+id/display_update_message"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_width="2dp"
          tools:layout="@layout/display_update_message" />

</LinearLayout>
```

It doesn't like the 'android:name="com.ila.tax_shield.fragments.ShowUpgradeDialogFragment"', and I'm not understanding why

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Make sure you are importing from the correct package when using `FragmentActivity` (`android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`)

Comment: When I do, it doesn't like the 'support' part of it. But shouldn't it be able to work using DialogFragment? I've edited it a bit to include some additional source code.

Comment: Do you want to show the `ShowUpgradeDialogFragment` embedded in the layout or as a dialog? Also, use `class="com.ila.tax_shield.fragments.ShowUpgradeDialogFragment"` instead of `android:name`.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my post to show the new code. Unfortunately, still the same results.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I forgot that calling finish() afterwards closed the whole activity, and therefore the FragmentDialog I was trying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you need to know is `AndroidManifest` is not the place where you declare your fragments. Take a look at the [docs here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) for a list valid items on the `Manifest` file.

Next, decide how you want to display `ShowUpgradeDialogFragment`. For a `DialogFragment` you have the below options

- Embed it in using the layout xml.
- Display it using the `FragmentManager`.

Now, if you want to embed it then just have your fragment in the layout xml,

OR
Do this

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new ShowUpgradeDialogFragment();
newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

Doing both of the above at the same time makes no sense to me.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. You answered some of the questions I had while trying to figure out my problem.

Comment: @DevinCrane No problems!

Comment: @DevinCrane If it helps solve your problem please click the "check" to mark the question as answered so that others who come around for similar problem might find it helpful.

Comment: For any wondering, Varun's post answered a lot of my questions, but in the end, it was solved by not calling finish() at the end of the code because it was closing the whole activity, and therefore the fragment. The offending 'finish()' was added to my original post and commented that it was removed. I couldn't vote Varun's answer up b/c my rep isn't high enough.